# Sending a video file via REST API to JIRA in Java

Tags: java, rest, post, jira, jira-rest-api

I am wanting to upload a video file (.mp4) by POST Request to JIRA. The file gets uploaded to the server, but the video becomes corrupt (i.e. opening it doesn't work). Sending other attachments, like screenshots (.png) and text files (.txt), works fine without corrupting the file.

I am using the Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 4.3.6.

Here is example code:

```
File file = new File("location/to/file.mp4");
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("file", file);

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost();
postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, BASIC_AUTH);
postRequest.addHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
postRequest.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
postRequest.setURI(uri);

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
} finally {
    client.close();
}
```

I attempted to add a `video/mp4` MIME type but that didn't seem to help any:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.create("video/mp4"), file.getName())
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue I had here was that QuickTime on Mac wasn't compatible with the .mp4 file format. I downloaded VLC media player and the file worked just fine without specifying a MIME type.